# Is this Database Model for university is correct

Tags: sql-server, database-design

The education system in our country is a little bit different from other countries. We take subjects all through the year and finish the year with the same subject. We have 4 main exams through the year (first exam, half-year exam, second exam, final year exam). I've made the below database model but I'm not sure if it's correct or not?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the network :) Imo, general schema review questions of this sort are [off-topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If you implement your model and have specific problems that arise, those may be more relevant. Otherwise, [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=dba.stackexchange.com) may be a better forum to get started with something this broad. If you have a more targeted question in regards to some of the more specific details in your question, perhaps you could elaborate on those issues in [an edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/248783/edit)?

Comment: The only definition of "correct" is if it meets all the business rules and can answer the queries required of it. Without this information in full we cannot help.

Comment: Thank you @michaelGreen

Comment: Thank you @peterVandivier I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are putting student's first name and last name in a separate table? There are rare chances of duplicate student name so it's not a good idea to create separate table to store student name. You can keep it with the entity/table "tbl_student". Likewise, we don't need to have separate table "tbl_Year".

At the same time, if you store "Male", "Female", "Neutral" or "M", "F", "N" as a value in the **Gender** column it will take more space on disk in compare to storing GenderId (with smallint datatype) referencing to new table "tbl_Gender".

Here you can also have a table to map subject & teacher with the class and then schedule a session in another table.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi sir sorry just about subject and teacher can you explian more and also the schedule

Comment: @Anas Instead of "Sir" you can tag specific user/contributor using "@UserName". Now coming to your query. I suggested creating a separate table where you can store a teacher's session on a particular subject in a particular class along with session start time and end time. If you need to store it.